# How to safely delete a QT::QTcpSocket?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp

[QTcpSocket * QTcpServer::nextPendingConnection () [virtual]](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtcpserver.html#nextPendingConnection)

> The socket is created as a child of the server, which means that it is
> automatically deleted **when the QTcpServer object is destroyed**. It is
> still a good idea to delete the object explicitly **when you are done
> with it**, to avoid wasting memory.

In my application, a `QTcpServer` lives for a long time (it disconnects from host when connection is closed but is never destroyed unless the program exits), and it accepts a lot of `QTcpServer::nextPendingConnection` and takes a lot of memory.

How should I delete the old QTcpSocket object before switching to the next pending one to save memory, while at the same time avoid double-delete?

Is `delete` ok in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is delete ok in this case?

Yes, thanks to the cleverness of Qt's object design.

In particular, QTcpSocket derives (eventually) from Object, and the QObject destructor method contains this code at the end:

```
if (d->parent)        // remove it from parent object
    d->setParent_helper(0);
```

So deleting the QTcpSocket object will automagically remove the QTcpSocket from the children-list of its parent object (in this case, the QTcpServer), so there will be no double-delete when the QTcpServer object is destroyed.

Comment: That is a really smart design. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

In any non-trivial code, you should rather call `deleteLater` on the `QTcpSocket` than `delete`ing it directly. The net result will be the same <sub><sub>(except in degenerate case when the event loop is already stopped)</sub></sub>, but it will guarantee that at the time of deletion your stack is already unwound back to the event loop. This will save you a **lot** of nerve tissue.

The reason for this is that, by design, a certain `QTcpServer`/`QTcpSocket` is always used from within a single thread (not necessarily the main a.k.a. GUI one, but a single one nevertheless), and in this case any slot connected to their signals will be called **directly from wherever the signal is emitted deep inside their bowels**. In general you have no idea what a Qt class will do when you return from your slot connected to its signal and control returns back to its guts. It might very well try to dereference the `QTcpSocket` you've just deleted, and the automagic mentioned by Jeremy won't help.

Another option is to always explicitly specify `Qt::QueuedConnection` when connecting to such signals.