# QT signal & slots inside second class

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slot

I have made a simple program:

Which run main program -> class program -> second class

**Let we see the code:**

main program:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
testqtc w; // this one intresting i call this 'first_class'
w.show();
return a.exec();
}
```

In 'first_class' I have :

```
    testqtc::testqtc(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    bool p = connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateCaption2()));
    std::cout << p;
    timer->start(1000);

    class1 class1(this); // i call this 'second class' which run under first class
}
void testqtc::updateCaption2(){
    std::cout << "first_class" << std::endl;
}
```

In 'second class' I have :

```
class1::class1(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    bool p = connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateCaption()));
    std::cout << p;
    timer->start(1000);
}
void class1::updateCaption(){
    std::cout << "second class" << std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
11first_class
first_class
first_class (-> and only first_class per second)
```

This is obvious that second class connector wont started.
Function connect return true, but the slot is not executing.

**How to use connect function in 'second_class' ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class1` instance is allocated on stack in `testqtc` constructor, that means that is destroyed before it can call the timeout slot, to solve it allocate it on heap:

```
class1* class1_ptr = new class1 (this);
```

Comment: or move class1 to a member object and initialize it in the initializer list rather than the constructor body.

Comment: @user3528438 the recommended way to allocate child QObjects (QObjects that have a parent) is the heap, if you allocate on the stack a QObject that has a parent you need to be careful for that object to be de-allocated before it's parent, but the pointer can be a member if necessary.

Comment: What's wrong if child being de-allocated before parent?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820450/how-to-safely-delete-a-qtqtcpsocket

Comment: Nothing, if the parent is deallocated first it's a problem

Comment: If parent lives shorter, why let it be parent?

Comment: I don't know why. I just said that if you allocate children on stack you need to be careful about the order of deallocations... So why not allocate on heap and let the parent delete it?

Comment: Because I'm RAII infected and I don't trust parents that much. Actually if I had to allocate it in constructor, I'd delete it in destructor.

Comment: RAII is nice, you can take a look at QPointer: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.4/qpointer.html#details